# How can I tell if my Perl program is part of a shell logical operation?

Tags: bash, shell, perl

To check if a Perl script is run "interactively" (not part of a pipeline), we can use `-t STDOUT` check, e.g. in:

```
% my-script
```

`t STDOUT` is true, while in:

```
% my-script | grep foo
```

`-t STDOUT` is false.

Is there a (simple) way to check if script is run "as a simple command", i.e.  not part of a multi-command logic sequence like:

```
% my-script && echo "success"
% my-script || echo "failed"
```

Comment: Short answer: no, there is not.

Comment: What would you like to do if you knew this?

Comment: I want to output differently depending on whether my CLI is accessed, e.g.: `image-is-landscape foo.jpg` vs `image-is-landscape foo.jpg && mv foo.jpg foo-landscape.jpg`. In the first case, I want to output a message "Image is landscape" in addition to returning appropriate exit code.

Comment: I've now adopted `grep`'s way of using `-q` option to let user suppress output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Effectively, you're asking if there's a way to check if the parent process will check the return value. There's no way to know what another process will or won't do in the future.